# Was the production team of E.T. (1982) movie aware that they have been using a look-alike toy of infamous Annabelle doll?

Tags: the-conjuring-universe, et-the-extra-terrestrial, annabelle

[image]

It caught my attention while watching [E.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.T._the_Extra-Terrestrial) in Amazon Prime that the doll they have used as a toy in the kids' bedroom is surprisingly very similar to the haunted "Annabelle doll", 1970.
That itself has 3 movies till date in the [Conjuring Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Conjuring_Universe).

[image]

When the film was made after 12 years of the real paranormal event, where the creators aware that they have been using a similar doll to the haunted one?

Comment: The pattern used for the doll is the rather popular Raggedy Ann doll - created in 1915, and has appeared in childrens' books since 1918, and also appeared in cartoons. It's probably in there simply because it's a typical toy for the times

Comment: HorusKol is totally correct.  Raggedy Ann dolls have been around forever.  There was an animated movie and TV specials in the late 1970's which created a surge in popularity in the doll through the early 80's.  Raggedy Ann is seen in other popular 80's movies.  Pretty sure she is in Poltergeist in the little girl's room as well, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: “Real paranormal event”? Maybe they just didn’t believe in real paranormal events…

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not a paranormal reference. It's the doll from the popular [Raggedy Ann franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raggedy_Ann), which sold 7 million book copies by 1940 and spawned a very popular line of dolls that were first made in 1960. (It was one of those dolls, bought in 1971, that would go on to gain fame as the "[Annabelle doll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annabelle_(doll))".)

For another example of how big she was culturally at the time, note that Raggedy Ann was in the [Macy's Thanksgiving Day Parade](https://macysthanksgiving.fandom.com/wiki/Raggedy_Ann) in 1975–1977, 1984–1986, and a few more recent years:

[image: Raggedy Ann float]

(Image from [Insider](https://www.insider.com/macys-thanksgiving-day-parade-photos-2017-11?amp))